# How to add a random perturbation term to the response variable, with transformation in R?

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to add a random perturbation term to my response variable (to estimate the impact of multicolinnearity in the beta estimates), but I am not sure on how to accomplish it when the response variable is transformed using a 1/4 power, in R.

Without any transformation in the response variable, according to Faraway's ["Linear Models with R,"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884258) the way to write it is:

```
g <- lm(hipcenter+10*rnorm(38) ~ ., seatpos).
```

So if I have a 1/4 power transformation for the response variable, then the code should be:

```
g <- lm((hipcenter^(1/4))+10*rnorm(38) ~ ., seatpos).
```

Is this right?

Comment: Why don't you construct another variable in your data.frame that is transformed and use that one in your model? Something along the lines of `seatpos$hipcenter_trans <- seatpos$hipcenter^(1/4) + 10 * rnorm(38)`. To answer your question, yes, you are powering your variable and adding some noise that has mean of ~0 and SD of 10.

Comment: Are you aware of the [perturb](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/perturb/index.html) package in R? It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I just wanted to thank Roman and Peter for their helpful advice.